# Push data into a javascript array from json_encode PHP

Tags: javascript, json

I am using a library that requires this kind of structure

```
 var items = [
  new primitives.orgdiagram.ItemConfig({
    id: 0,
    parent: null,
    title: "Scott Aasrud",
    description: "Root",
    phone: "1 (416) 001-4567",
    email: "scott.aasrud@mail.com",
    image: "demo/images/photos/a.png",
    itemTitleColor: primitives.common.Colors.RoyalBlue
  }),
  new primitives.orgdiagram.ItemConfig({
    id: 1,
    parent: 0,
    title: "Ted Lucas",
    description: "Left",
    phone: "1 (416) 002-4567",
    email: "ted.lucas@mail.com",
    image: "demo/images/photos/b.png",
    itemTitleColor: primitives.common.Colors.RoyalBlue
  }),
];

options.items = items;
```

How can I push data retrieved from my PHP json to the array? The one that confuses me is the

```
new primitives.orgdiagram.ItemConfig
```

The json that is retrieved from my PHP is this part

```
id: 0,
parent: null,
title: "Scott Aasrud",
description: "Root",
phone: "1 (416) 001-4567",
email: "scott.aasrud@mail.com",
image: "demo/images/photos/a.png",
itemTitleColor: primitives.common.Colors.RoyalBlue
```

can somebody help me please??

thank you :)

Comment: That is not JSON. How exactly are you receiving that from PHP?

Comment: Please return JSON format on PHP and you could use ajax to get data to javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code. In case JSON has multiple objects use a for loop to push the values into the array.

```js
var items = [];

var item1 = new primitives.orgdiagram.ItemConfig({
  id: 0,
  parent: null,
  title: "Scott Aasrud",
  description: "Root",
  phone: "1 (416) 001-4567",
  email: "scott.aasrud@mail.com",
  image: "demo/images/photos/a.png",
  itemTitleColor: primitives.common.Colors.RoyalBlue
});

items.push(item1);
```

Comment: sir, what if the result from PHP returns more than 1 data? can you guide me on how to create the loop function?

Comment: Use a for loop!

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir, So i am thinking that what I need to do is first push the data from PHP retrieved into an array first ? Am i correct?